# How to create a WCF reply service for AJAX unit testing

Tags: ajax, wcf, json, wcf-binding

I want to create a WCF service that will simply reply back the query string, HTTP headers, and the HTTP verb used in a request it received.

I want to use it to unittest a AJAX enabled JavaScript framework I am building so I can verify that the HTTP headers and HTTP verbs are being set correctly.

Basically I need a way to make the WCF service bind to HTTP GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE, and I need a way to grab all the headers etc. and return them.

Any input is much appreciated, Egil.

Comment: Have you looked at `System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out a HTTP handler was an easier way to go than a WCF service. I posted my solution over at my blog: [Simple Ping/Reply Service for Unit Testing AJAX/XHR requests](http://egilhansen.com/2010/09/09/simple-pingreply-service-for-unit-testing-ajaxxhr-requests/). I hope this helps others as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that it is possible to do exactly what you want to do. But you could come close using REST with WCF, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529.aspx